# Migrate changing column from float to double changing higher values in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, double, precision

I'm trying to make a migrate that changes the column type from **float** to **double**, because the float type rounds off some values in the database, such as:

**posted value:** 23337840
**value in database with column type float:** 23337800

**posted value:** 23337870
**value in database with column type float:** 3337900

When I run the migrate to double these values are corrected to the correct one, with due precision, however values like 1 trillion are wrong.

**value in column in float type:** 1000000000000
**value in column in double type:** 999999995904

*Note*: When a new insert is made in the database with the column in double type with a value of 1 trillion, the value is correct. The error only occurs when a value is migrated from float to double.

Does anyone know why this occurs since the double should accept larger values? And what way can it be done so that these values already in the database remain correct?

Comment: You really should use DECIMAL if you need the precision (e.g. right of decimal point) or INTEGER if you don't (like all the numbers in this post). DECIMAL and INTEGER are referred to as "exact numeric data types" where as both FLOAT and DOUBLE are called "approximate numeric data types" (per MySQL documentation). (I have never used the latter for any application). As for how you correct (if you can) what you have already tried/implemented I will allow someone with a bit more DBA experience to comment on that.

Comment: When storing 1,000,000,000,000 as a single precision binary float, it becomes 999,999,995,904. If you convert that stored 999,999,995,904 to double precision, it stays 999,999,995,904 – the precision loss already occurred.

Comment: @engineersmnky I also tried using DECIMAL with precision 64 and scale 12 and it still rounded the value. For example:

value in column in float type: 1000000000000
value in column in decimal(64,12) type: 999999995904.000000000000

Comment: @Stefan When I store 1,000,000,000,000 as a float, the value in the database remains correct, not changed or rounded. It is only in the migration of the column type (float to double, or float to decimal) that the value in the database is changed.

Comment: @LuanaMaia 1,000,000,000,000 cannot be represented exactly as a single precision (32-bit) float. The closest 32-bit float is slightly lower: 999,999,995,904. The next higher 32-bit float is already 1,000,000,061,440. The former one is what's being stored within the database if you have a FLOAT (32-bit) column. However, if you have a DOUBLE (64-bit) column (or a DECIMAL with high precision), the value _can_ be stored exactly. That's why entering new values works as expected whereas old values (those from the former FLOAT column) retain their precision loss.

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL `FLOAT` database column stores (by default) 32-bit [single precision floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). These values have limited precision which becomes most obvious for very small or very large numbers. For example, these are the available 32-bit floating point values closest to 1,000,000,000,000: (with their respective difference)

```
 999999799296.0  # -200,704
 999999864832.0  # -135,168
 999999930368.0  #  -69,632
 999999995904.0  #   -4,096
1000000061440.0  #  +61,440
1000000126976.0  # +126,976
1000000192512.0  # +192,512
```

If you have a value in-between, it will be converted to the closest float available. Attempting to store the integer 1,000,000,000,000 as a 32-bit float will actually store 999,999,995,904.0 because that's the closest value available, "only" off by 4,096.

The values `FLOAT` can represent is a subset of the values `DOUBLE` can represent. Which means that converting a column from `FLOAT` to `DOUBLE` is a lossless operation. There's no further precision loss, its numeric value won't change. However, there's no way to reconstruct the original value from the 32-bit float, i.e. converting 999,999,995,904.0 from FLOAT to DOUBLE will still be 999,999,995,904.0.

Storing new values into a DOUBLE column *do* benefit from the higher precision. That's why you can have 1,000,000,000,000.0 in your `DOUBLE` column.

Note that floats in Ruby are 64 bit nowadays, i.e. Ruby's `Float` corresponds to MySQL's `DOUBLE`.